# another object of a class acts differently ,JavaSource_Calendar class

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have a class called JavaSource_Calendar which was downloaded from internet.
now the problem is when I make an object out of it and use it for the first time ,it works great but when I make another object out of it and use it for the second time it gives me wrong values!!!

```
JavaSource_Calendar calenderFrom = new JavaSource_Calendar();
calenderFrom.setIranianDate(1391, 12, 8);
String MiladiDate_FROM = calenderFrom.getGregorianDate();
Log.d("miladi from is: ", MiladiDate_FROM);

JavaSource_Calendar calenderTo = new JavaSource_Calendar();
calenderTo.setIranianDate(1391, 12, 12);
String MiladiDate_TO = calenderTo.getGregorianDate();
Log.d("miladi to is: ", MiladiDate_TO);
```

As I said the first 4 lines of code gives correct result but the next 4 lines of code doesn't.

UPDATE:
here is the link to that calendar class file: 
http://neemasakhtemani.com/upload/JavaSource_Calendar.java

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with it. However, as we don't know anything about the class, or what you expected the results to be, or what the actual results are, there's not a lot we can do to help you. (I'd recommend using Joda Time for date/time work if at all possible...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I uploaded the class.

Comment: And the answer you expected was...?

Comment: clean project solved the problem, thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

I have just executed the code. It seems fine to me

Here is what I get:

```
miladi from is: 2013/2/26
miladi to is: 2013/3/2
```

If this is not what you want, what are you expecting clearly ?

Comment: I got the same result as you after I did a clean project in eclipse. eclipse is so buggy and wasted 30 minutes of my life. thanks for respond.

Comment: @scnscn: I wouldn't be quite so quick to blame Eclipse. You should take some time to work out how you could have written your question better - you could have saved everyone involved a lot of time. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints